# Webpack unable to view Vue file

Tags: ruby, vue.js, webpack

Some reason I can't get my Vue project up and running. I have another project with the exact same settings and versions that's working fine, but with this install I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR in ./app/javascript/components/app.vue
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
```

Here is my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@rails/webpacker": "3.5",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "v-clipboard": "^2.0.1",
    "vue": "2.5.16",
    "vue-loader": "14.2.2",
    "vue-router": "3.0.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "2.5.16",
    "vuelidate": "^0.7.4",
    "vuetify": "^1.3.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.11.2"
  }
}
```

My `app.vue` file:

```
<template>
  <v-app class="my_background">
    <h1>hi</h1>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
import 'images/background.png';
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  data: function() {
    return{};
  }
};    
</script>
```

And then finally my webpack config file.

```
const { dev_server: devServer } = require('@rails/webpacker').config

const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
const inDevServer = process.argv.find(v => v.includes('webpack-dev-server'))
const extractCSS = !(inDevServer && (devServer && devServer.hmr)) || isProduction

module.exports = {
  test: /\.vue(\.erb)?$/,
  use: [{
    loader: 'vue-loader',
    options: { extractCSS }
  }]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your webpack configuration does not handle load of `png` (or any image files).

For loading image, at least [url-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/url-loader) is required.

And you can follow a [guide](https://medium.com/a-beginners-guide-for-webpack-2/handling-images-e1a2a2c28f8d) to setup webpack `url-loader` correctly.

Comment: no.. no luck and my other projects with almost the exact same code don't use those packages either.. but they work fine